# Java socketserver: How to handle many incoming connections?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, connection

I am writing a simple multithreaded socketserver and I am wondering how best to handle incoming connections:

1. create a new thread for each new connection.   The number of concurrent threads would be limited and waiting connections limited by specifying a backlog
2. add all incoming connections into a queue and have a pool of worker threads that process the queue

I am inclined to go for option 2 because I really don't want to refuse any connections, even under high loads, but I am wondering if there are any considerations I should be aware of with accepting effectively unlimited connections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With unlimited connections you potentially can create a huge number of threads. That means a lot of processing is required, plus each thread will consume a fixed amount of memory by default merely for the heap (I think the figure is 512kB *per thread*, but that may be platform dependent).

By pooling a fixed number of threads and accepting a limited number of clients you will ensure that some of your clients will be serviced in a reasonable time period, and your server won't collapse from overloading.

You may want to check out [this article on building servers using NIO](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/09/01/nio.html) or perhaps check out frameworks such as [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/).

Comment: as a (I assume fixed size) thread pool is being used the number of threads would not be unlimited and instead bounded by the size of the pool.

Comment: Sorry - think I confused matters by writing 'polling', not 'pooling'

Comment: Thanks - Apache Mina is fantastic and exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

> I really don't want to refuse any
>   connections

Actually you probably do. When you're overloaded, you want to retain enough capacity to get rid of the current load before you accept any more. Slowing everdybody to a halt isn't any more acceptable than refusing connections.

Queueing theory says that the sweet spot is about 70% utilization. If your server is going to have a steady load higher than that get faster hardware until it doesn't.

Having said that, if you're expecting hundreds of thousands of connections I would use a thread pool or NIO. If you're only expecting thousands, a thread per connection is much the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you accept unlimited connections, and your processing isn't fast enough to cope with the stream of incoming connections, your queue will fill up - until it reaches a point, where it takes so long to process previous requests, that most requests won't even be interested in the answer anymore, as soon as you get to them.

Answer (score 2):

1 Thread per connection does not scale. Read about it at The [C10K](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) problem. It is a long read, but very famous.

I would advise to learn about [NIO](http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs161/papers/j-nio-ltr.pdf) or rather use the impressive [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) framework which handles all the heavy-lifting(NIO) for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I really don't want to refuse any connections, even under high loads

Your option 2 is the only way to go in my opinion. You should have one pinned NIO selector thread per each 5-10k connections. But nothing can delay this critical thread, so you use a DEMUX to distribute work among a fixed number of pinned threads **and not to a thread pool**. And a MUX to collect work and respond back to clients. As EJP said, if your worker threads are lagging, eventually you will have to drop connections **unless you start dumping messages to disk to make your queue as large as possible**. That way y won't be dropping any connection, even under high loads. You can check [this article](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2015/01/architecture-case-study-1-coralreactor-coralqueue/) which explain this in detail and the diagram below:

[image]

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the developers of CoralQueue